# Beginner - Basic Trig Table

Tags: java, math

I am taking an intro to Java course, and am currently working on one of my weekly assignments. I have it almost done except I cannot figure out how to make this table (up to 180 degres)
:
[image: Java Table]

I'm assuming I need to use nested for loops of some sort, and that I need to use sin, cos, and tan in my println, but other than that I'm clueless.

Thank you.

Comment: you don't need a nested loop

Comment: OK. So the first step is: How do you print one line of that table (after the header)? How about the line with Angle 0.0; get us started, how can you print that?

Comment: One (bad) way to do it: `String table = "Angle  Sin     Cos     Tan\n-----  ---     ---     ---\n
0.0    0.0     1.0     0.0\n5.0    0.0872  0.9962  0.0875\n10.0   0.1736  0.9848  0.1763 ... "`

Comment: I can get one of the numbers to print, using something like this:   double x = 0;
  
  System.out.print(Math.sin(x));

Comment: Initial conditions: check. Ending condition: check. Angle increment: check. Print statements: check. Math functions: check. What are you missing?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this piece of code will give you an idea of how to format the table and help you with your assignment (if that is the problem).

```
public class Table {

//badly formatted example (with meaningless values)
public static void main(String[] args) {

    int rows = 10;
    double sin = 0;
    double cos = 0;
    double tan = 0;

    for (int j = 1; j <= rows; j++){    

        // print values
        System.out.print(sin + "    ");
        System.out.print(cos + "    ");
        System.out.print(tan + "    ");
        System.out.println();                                   

        //modify values;
        sin = sin + 1;
        cos = cos + 2;
        tan = tan + 3;
    }           
}
```

}